# Domain not configuring on XAMPP instead of localhost

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

7-Months back I had a discussion [here](https://laravel.io/forum/laravel-htaccess-and-no-login-register-pages-found). Then n my Laptop I was easily able to configure the local domain by the name of `WordPress.test`, based on how and what I was told there. everything was working fine. I installed xampp on my desktop today and did the same.

The same file was available at [2 different paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeC38.png).

I put this code in both the files:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE 
    <Directory "F:\codegorithm\wordpress">  #any path to which you wish to apply gzip compression to!
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
        <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
            AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
        </IfModule>
    </Directory> 
    DocumentRoot "F:\codegorithm\wordpress"  
    ServerName wordpress.test
</VirtualHost>
```

It doesn't connect in the browser and gives [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPC9R.png) (XAMPP restarted many times).

Comment: I am new, not allowed to embed images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. This file was also to be fixed → `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` = hosts.

```
#
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 wordpress.test
```

[image]